# Using variables from another python file without the need of using "script.variable"

Tags: python

I am trying to import another python file to be able to use its variables and everything is working well and I figured it out. But how do I make it so I don't have to put the python file name before the used variable?

```
import pygame
import variables
pygame.init()


def draw_task():
    pygame.draw.circle(variables.screen, variables.white, (960, 540), 20, 5)


running = True
while running:
    variables.timer.tick(variables.FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    variables.screen.fill(variables.background)
    draw_task()
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

using my code as an example. How do I make it so I don't have to put variables.white, variables.screen etc.?

Comment: `from variables import timer, screen`

Comment: from variables import *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

```
from variables import timer, screen
```

Or if you just want to type a little less:

```
import variables as var

var.timer.tick(var.FPS)
```

Comment: for my case using from variables import * works the easiest. and doesn't require me to put variables.timer or anything.timer and I can just use the variable freely.